# Android app restarts during gallery intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

My app launches the gallery to choose a photo. In the meantime, my app gets killed by the operating system, so that when I select the image my app needs to start up all over again.

**NOTE: this is a transient issue. It often works just fine.**

When it fails, there is *nothing at all in the logs* to indicate that a anything went wrong.

The gallery is launched in the usual way via `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

**Why is my app being terminated?** I can only assume it is a memory issue (caused by the Gallery app?), except that:

- It happens with small images, too.
- When it works successfully my app has no issues processing the
  images.
- I'm using `android:largeHeap="true"`. `activityManager.getMemoryClass()` = 256MB.
- The issue happens more often when the debugger is connected.
- A photo, even uncompressed, is probably no more than 30MB. At the time of launching the gallery,  my system has 199MB available.

Even when the app restarts, the `onActivityResult` method is still called, so I can still resume the upload, but it makes for a very slow process and an awful user experience.

(Running Jellybean on Samsung Galaxy S3)

Comment: `my app needs to start up all over again`. What is so awfull on that? Are you using the instance state parameter of onCreate()?

Comment: My app needs to fetch data over the internet every time the app starts up - therefore a restart during an image upload makes everything about 10 seconds slower than it ought to be. This is unacceptable user experience in my opinion.

Comment: And when you rotate your device? How do you handle that? You will not download all again i suppose? `Are you using the instance state parameter of onCreate()?` Why dont you answer that?

Comment: Rotating the device does not trigger `onCreate()` or even `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Yes, I am using the instance state parameter, that is how I am able to resume the upload after a restart. I can not serialise the entire app state as I am running a webview which is making the network requests.

Answer (score 0):

try this bro,
`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),123);`

Comment: How is this different from what I have already? I have tried with a chooser, but still seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
```

Comment: I tried ACTION_PICK - still seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:-

```
 private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
```

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);`

In ActivityResult

`if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
{
//do something
}`

And make sure you have added these in manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I have done all of that. There is nothing missing from my code, as it often works just fine.